Gaussian Markov Random Field fitting in GAMLSS with coordinates (UTMs)
I am building a model in gamlss with presence/absence ecological data (binary) that are spatially correlated. It appears my primary option in gamlss is to include a MRF additive term within the GAMLSS model, but all the vignettes/posts I have found so far only provide examples with neighboring polygons. Can anyone provide some example code for how to build a gmrf term using coordinates (UTMs or lat/long) associated with each observation? Or is this function only possible with polygons?
I initially tried specifying the correlation structure in a gamm model, but recently found other posts that indicate PQL does not perform well with binary data. I also tried sdmTMB, but several of my covariates are nonlinear and I have found the smoothing function within sdmTMB to be limited/challenging to visualize (especially because I would like to use penalized b-splines). Although gamm4 works well with binary data, there is no option for a correlation structure that I am aware of.

If you want to model the spatial component through the model's mean structure you can do this with the normal thin plate splines or Duchon splines (if using mgcv), assuming you are using projected coordinates. A tensor product may be better for lat/lon data. If you want to model the spatial component through the error structure then you are out of luck with mgcv or gamlss. I would suggest using brms or glmmTMB but note in latter spline handling is in its infancy. If distinction btw mean structure or error structure then see Hefley et al (1027)

You could also do exactly what you ask (an intrinsic Gaussian MRF) by creating a mesh over the spatial locations using a triangulation or even the meshes that INLA uses; see the fmesher package for an R way to create the mesh. You don't need to do this; a spatial smoother should be fine and they'll only differ in minor details of the basis functions that are formed/used.
